# Erros image Docker with PHP and twig

Tags: php, docker, symfony, twig, dockerfile

I'm having trouble installing Synfony and Twig on my docker.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Twig \ Environment' not found in /var/www/html/... appears.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php: 7.2-apache

#Install unzip, composer,
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php - --install-dir = / usr / local / bin --filename = composer \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y git libzip-dev unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && a2enmod rewrite headers \

COPY src / / var / www / html /
    
#Enable Twig and Symfony
RUN cd / var / www && composer require "twig / twig: ^ 3.0"
RUN composer require "symfony / form"
```

My Controller

```php
protected function load (string $ view, $ param = [])
{
    $twig = new \Twig\Environment((new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader ('../app/site/view/')),
        ['debug' => false]
    );
    $ twig->addGlobal ('BASE', BASE);
    echo $twig->render($view . '.twig.php', $params);
}
```

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: I believe `RUN [command]` runs that command as root. which possibly might interfere with the access rights apache/php-fpm has on that folder. also your docker stuff contains way too many spaces around slashes. finally, your docker file should produce output if the installation didn't work. if it did work, maybe you didn't include the vendor/autoload.php? if you did that too, you should maybe expand that error message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and helped to find the error, while checking the permission I found the error where it was running in the wrong folder.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse me, I was so focused on the error that the error went unnoticed.
I was running composer in the wrong folder

```
COPY src/ /var/www/html/

RUN cd/var/www && composer require "twig/twig:^3.0"
```

It was running on www, but the app is on www/html

I'm sorry...